# Why are all the keys examined for an indexed mongos query with a sort and limit?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongos setup with 2 shards and the following data:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) { 
    db.items.insert({item: "a", i_type: "x", i_id: i, price: i * 50});
    db.items.insert({item: "a", i_type: "y", i_id: i, price: i * 50});
    db.items.insert({item: "b", i_type: "x", i_id: i, price: i * 50});
    db.items.insert({item: "b", i_type: "y", i_id: i, price: i * 50});
}
db.items.createIndex({item: 1, i_type: 1, i_id: 1}, {unique: true})
db.items.createIndex({item: 1, i_type: 1, price: 1})
sh.enableSharding("test")
sh.shardCollection("test.items", {item: 1, i_type: 1})
```

I run this:

```
db.items.find(
    {item: "a", i_type: {$in: ["x", "y"]}},
    {_id: 0, item: 1, i_type: 1}
).sort({price: 1}).limit(10).explain("executionStats")
```

And get the following `executionStats`:

```
"nReturned" : NumberInt(10), 
"executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(22), 
"totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(2000), 
"totalDocsExamined" : NumberInt(2000), 
"executionStages" : {
    "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD", 
    "nReturned" : NumberInt(10), 
    "executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(22), 
    "totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(2000), 
    "totalDocsExamined" : NumberInt(2000), 
    "totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(21), 
    "shards" : [
        {
            "shardName" : "rs1", 
            "executionSuccess" : true, 
            "executionStages" : {
                "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
                "nReturned" : NumberInt(10), 
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                "works" : NumberInt(2013), 
                "advanced" : NumberInt(10), 
                "needTime" : NumberInt(2002), 
                "needFetch" : NumberInt(0), 
                "saveState" : NumberInt(47), 
                "restoreState" : NumberInt(47), 
                "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
                "transformBy" : {
                    "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "item" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "i_type" : NumberInt(1)
                }, 
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT", 
                    "nReturned" : NumberInt(10), 
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "works" : NumberInt(2013), 
                    "advanced" : NumberInt(10), 
                    "needTime" : NumberInt(2001), 
                    "needFetch" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "saveState" : NumberInt(47), 
                    "restoreState" : NumberInt(47), 
                    "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
                    "sortPattern" : {
                        "price" : NumberInt(1)
                    }, 
                    "memUsage" : NumberInt(850), 
                    "memLimit" : NumberInt(33554432), 
                    "limitAmount" : NumberInt(10), 
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH", 
                        "nReturned" : NumberInt(2000), 
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                        "works" : NumberInt(2001), 
                        "advanced" : NumberInt(2000), 
                        "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
                        "needFetch" : NumberInt(0), 
                        "saveState" : NumberInt(47), 
                        "restoreState" : NumberInt(47), 
                        "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                        "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
                        "docsExamined" : NumberInt(2000), 
                        "alreadyHasObj" : NumberInt(0), 
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER", 
                            "nReturned" : NumberInt(2000), 
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                            "works" : NumberInt(2001), 
                            "advanced" : NumberInt(2000), 
                            "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
                            "needFetch" : NumberInt(0), 
                            "saveState" : NumberInt(47), 
                            "restoreState" : NumberInt(47), 
                            "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                            "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
                            "chunkSkips" : NumberInt(0), 
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                                "nReturned" : NumberInt(2000), 
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                                "works" : NumberInt(2001), 
                                "advanced" : NumberInt(2000), 
                                "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
                                "needFetch" : NumberInt(0), 
                                "saveState" : NumberInt(47), 
                                "restoreState" : NumberInt(47), 
                                "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                                "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "item" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "i_type" : NumberInt(1), 
                                    "price" : NumberInt(1)
                                }, 
                                "indexName" : "item_1_i_type_1_price_1", 
                                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                                "direction" : "forward", 
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "item" : [
                                        "[\"a\", \"a\"]"
                                    ], 
                                    "i_type" : [
                                        "[\"x\", \"x\"]", 
                                        "[\"y\", \"y\"]"
                                    ], 
                                    "price" : [
                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                "keysExamined" : NumberInt(2000), 
                                "dupsTested" : NumberInt(0), 
                                "dupsDropped" : NumberInt(0), 
                                "seenInvalidated" : NumberInt(0), 
                                "matchTested" : NumberInt(0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am struggling to understand why all the keys containing `{item: "a", i_type: "x"}` and `{item: "a", i_type: "y"}` need to be examined on the shard. The explain suggests it is using the appropriate index.

If I run the same query on the replica set where the documents reside my `totalKeysExamined` is 10. If I remove the sort or query for a single `i_type` on mongos the `totalKeysExamined` are 10 (or 11 depending on auto-balancing). All of these query plans have an `executionStage` of `LIMIT` that is distinctly missing from the explain I have posted above.

Depending on how the auto-balancer decides to do things the first `executionStage` in the hierarchy may be `SHARD_MERGE_SORT` instead of `SINGLE_SHARD`, but even if the query needed to fetch information from both shards I would assume only 20 keys would need to be examined (10 from each shard).

Is this a limitation of mongos that I am running into, a situation where I need to improve my choice of shard key and indexes, or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit `$or` builds the query plan the way I would expect. I have filed a [bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21628) related to this issue.

```
db.items.find(
    {$or: [{item: "a", i_type: "x"}, {item: "a", i_type: "y"}]},
    {_id: 0, item: 1, i_type: 1}
).sort({price: 1}).limit(10).explain("executionStats")
```